# Angular add markup within custom pipe

Tags: angular, pipe

i want to create a custom pipe `highlightPipe` which adds a `<mark>` to highlight text using a css class:

```
 {{ 'i am some random text' | highlight:'some' }}
```

which will be translated to

`I am <mark>some</mark> random text`

However when I implmement the pipe the result is escaped in the final page. E.g it does actually show `<mark>some</mark>`

Is there a way to tell the pipe that she is allowed to add real HTML?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use innerHtml property to display the content as html.

```
<div [innerHTML]="textToBeDisplay | highlight:'some'"></div>
```

Also make sure you use the DomSanitizer in your pipes as well.

```
return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(textToBeDisplay);
```

Comment: I wonder if it can be done by using a directive?
```<div highlight>
  {{mytext}}
</div>```